# Is this theorem in Samuel's Algebraic theory of numbers true?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am not convinced by both the statement of the theorem and the given proof. Here it is:
Theorem 1: Let K be a field of characteristic zero or a finite field, let K' be an extension of finite degree n of K, and let C be an algraically closed field containing K. Then there exist n distinct K-*isomorphisms* of K' into C.

The problem is that if K is finite, so is K' which then can't be isomorphic to an algebraically closed field (since algebraically closed field imply infinite).

The proof goes  like this:

Our assertion is true for any extension field K' of the form K[x] with x in K'. In fact, the minimal polynomial F(X) of x over k is then of degree n. It has n roots x_1,...,x_n in C, all of which are distinct according to the lemma (*a previous lemma I am ok with*). For any any i=1,...,n we have then a K-isomorphism from K' to C. he continue

I can't see why this last claim is true. I know there is an isomorphism from K(x_i) to K(x_j), which you can probably extend to an homomorphism from  K(x_i) to C. But that's all.

Sorry for the appearence, it's my first time and don't see where to click to start the latex format. I really need to get this clear since this result is used in a few times throughout the text and the isomorphism claim in a crucial way at some point.

Comment: This means that there exist exactly $n$ embeddings $K' \longrightarrow C$ fixing $K$. He calls them "isomorphisms" because $K'$ is actually isomorphic to the images of these maps.

Comment: I see, but I am not sure about it since,in other instances, he uses the word "isomorphism" in the usual sense.

Comment: Crostul is correct. The key word is 'into', in contrast with 'onto'. This usage is not uncommon in older literature.

Comment: Ok then. After checking closely, I see I was wrong when I thought he uses surjectivity in a later proof of a proposition using this theorem.So he is consistent with your interpretation. If any of you post his comment as a answer, I will accept it so as not to leave an unanswered question.